# Is the number of MySQL procs (average) at 0.39 is a lot?

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, shared-hosting

Can someone tell me whether the number of MySQL procs (average) at 0.39 is a lot??? I've gotten it down from 1.18 - 1.24 range. Our shared hosting provider says their limit is .4. Our site is not real big, though does make use of 5 DBs and has several pages that connect to the various DBs. To me it doesn't seem like a lot, but I have no frame of reference. Site traffic has pretty much been the same for the last 9 months. We’re averaging 108/visits per day and 5,234 page views a month. Most DB tables are small, the two largest are around 6,200 records and the other is around 350,000 records. The large one I was planning on archiving some old un-necessary data from several years ago and re-indexing to help performance, though not sure if this is an issue.

Comment: May I ask what "MySQL procs" are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like kind of a lot to me, yeah, for the kind of traffic you're talking about.  I suspect you have some slow queries going on that would benefit from better indexing, or maybe some lengthy maintenance jobs.  You might want to look into [MySQL's slow query logging faculty](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: So, would re-indexing old tables and reducing the number of records help this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure what "re-indexing" means to you, but if it means changing around the indices according to what's needed by the queries that are being carried out, then yeah, definitely.  Reducing record counts may or may not do anything; very situational, and the better your indexes are the less it will accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. Anything else I can do to reduce the number of processes? Is the 'MySQL's slow query logging faculty' something I could do in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: I would just focus entirely on performance optimization; faster queries almost always means fewer queries running per unit of time, on average.  I don't think you'd be able to configure your own slow query logging in a shared environment, but your hosting provider may have it enabled or be willing to enable it for a while so you can get some stats.  It's in their interest for you to use less of their resources, after all.

Comment: Hey, uh, you should also just eyeball a couple dozen `SHOW PROCESSLIST` (and `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` if need be) queries and see if anything leaps out at you.  Not sure if that goes without saying or not.

Comment: I couldn't get the host to provide me with a process list as it's a shared server.

Comment: That shouldn't actually be an obstacle.  You should be able to just run those queries against a MySQL connection, and it's supposed to just show you the threads you own.  (cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html)

Comment: Great. I'll take a look and see if I can figure this out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, tried to run those two SHOW PROCESSLIST and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST in the SQL command line of PHPMYAdmin...and didn't get any results, should I do this differently? Sorry, never had to do this so it's new to me, but what I read said I could.

Comment: I get something like this for each DB. 5076250 username localhost dbname Query 0 NULL SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST. That's it for each DB.

Comment: That's not unusual; if your average is 0.39, then more than half the time you have no queries running.  My advice is to keep throwing `SHOW PROCESSLIST` at the server until you see something show up.

Comment: It's actually risen to .49, but still nothing. I'll keep trying and look at my queries. Thanks.

Comment: That's odd.  Maybe verify that your PHPMyAdmin is pointing at the right server.

Comment: It's right, I can see the five diff DBs, just nothing shows for SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST or SHOW PROCESSLIST.

Comment: Okay.  I dunno, then.  Must be something interesting about the setup.

Comment: Chaos, thanks for your advice and help thus far. I've gone in and optimized my queries and improved them with indexes that were not there. I've used the EXPLAIN function to help determine and verify results and they should be a lot better. However, the number of process hasn't gone down. I'm sitting at .43 - 1/24, .41 - 1/25 and currently .41 for today (1/26). I optimized them last night (1/25)...any thoughts/suggestions? Also, I noticed the server is defined as 'localhost', does this mean that the DB server is on the same box as the web server? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, something counterintuitive is definitely going on.  What I immediately suspect is that your main Web site activity is not actually responsible for the bulk of the database load, and some kind of maintenance process or the like (do you have cron jobs set up?) is doing it.  And honestly, if I were you I would be getting really sick of not having full control of my database server.  At the least, I'd be pestering my host for some `SHOW PROCESSLIST` results cropped to only show my processes.  And yeah, barring high weirdness, DB server being localhost means it's on the same machine.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sick of this whole thing as I've never had an issue like this. No cron jobs. The only thing I had gotten from the host on the process list was four sleeping connections. Tried to get more from them and they said 'Server MySQL process list is not available under shared user access since it contains MySQL details of other accounts sharing the server. Secondly, MySQL queries keep coming every second.' I'm beginning to think that they have done a crummy job installing/configuring the server.

Comment: Possibly you need to get details on exactly how they calculate your average procs.  I'm starting to suspect that they're counting a sleeping connection as 0.10 procs.

Comment: If I've optimized 85% of the site's queries with indexes using EXPLAIN and have improved their speed/efficiency I should see a drop in resources. If there was no other issue, that would be the case, correct?

Comment: Yeah the lowest I've gotten it down to was .26 and .27 this past weekend.

Comment: One would think so, yeah.  There are a lot of weird possible reasons that wouldn't be the case, but without seeing any in evidence, that'd be my expectation.  Part of my thinking is this: if they're counting a sleeping connection as 0.10 procs, then you *did* see a significant drop in resource usage, because 0.40 is your baseline, and you saw a drop from 0.43 to 0.41, representing your actual resource usage dropping by 66%, which is the kind of shift I would expect from a good query optimization pass.

Comment: One way you could readily test this proposition is, if you're using `mysql_pconnect`, experimentally switch to `mysql_connect`, so that your connections stop persisting.  (It will take a while for the current ones to die off, not sure how long.)  This will hurt performance somewhat because your scripts will have to set up and tear down fresh connections each time, but it'll tell you whether something is fishy about your host's accounting.

Comment: i.e. if you switch to `mysql_connect` and the next day your average procs drops to 0.01, then they're counting sleeping connections.

Comment: I'm not using mysql_pconnect in any of my code, the old code is in ASP and I'm not real familiar with that, so it may be possible that is. I inherited that part of the site and DB, but went in and optimized the tables since they didn't have any indexes. The usage in general is way down. It was as high as 1.26 and 1.18 until I put a stop to a bunch of bots hitting the site.

Comment: It's frustrating. I think I'm going to look into a new host. Their resource limit is .4 which is why I'm struggling with it. I'd like to know what the issue is before I move hosts, but may not be able to find out.